# Compiling without libc

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, demo, libc

I want to compile my C-code without the (g)libc. How can I deactivate it and which functions depend on it?

I tried -nostdlib but it doesn't help: The code is compilable and runs, but I can still find the name of the libc in the hexdump of my executable.

Comment: `-nostdlib` should do it, what platform/compiler version are you using?

Comment: "doesn't help" as in that didn't disable the library, or you couldn't compile anything with that flag?

Comment: You probably also want -nostartupfiles.

Comment: There is no -nostartupfiles option.  You probably mean -nostartfiles, which is already implied by -nostdlib.

Comment: Here is an excellent article on optimizing elf binaries which covers stripping stdlib off executables: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux ](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you compile your code with `-nostdlib`, you won't be able to call any C library functions (of course), but you also don't get the regular C bootstrap code.  In particular, the real entry point of a program on Linux is not `main()`, but rather a function called `_start()`.  The standard libraries normally provide a version of this that runs some initialization code, then calls `main()`.

Try compiling this with `gcc -nostdlib -m32`:

```
// Tell the compiler incoming stack alignment is not RSP%16==8 or ESP%16==12
__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))
void _start() {

    /* main body of program: call main(), etc */

    /* exit system call */
    asm("movl $1,%eax;"
        "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );
    __builtin_unreachable();  // tell the compiler to make sure side effects are done before the asm statement
}
```

The `_start()` function should always end with a call to `exit` (or other non-returning system call such as `exec`).  The above example invokes the system call directly with inline assembly since the usual `exit()` is not available.

Comment: For 64 bit, the assembly code has to look like this: `asm("mov rax,60; mov rdi,0; syscall")`.

Comment: Adding to @sigalor's comment, to compile with `gcc` you will need to use AT&T syntax so this should look like the following: `asm(mov $60,%rax; mov $0,%rdi; syscall)`

Comment: @ataylor: why _start() function should always end with call to exit() ? What if I don't write exit() in start() function ?

Comment: @Destructor on my system, it hangs for a few seconds, then segfaults.

Comment: ```$ gcc -nostdlib main.c                                                            

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have to combine -nostdlib with -nostartfiles (now?), in my experience, to get the magic stripped-down no-main experience.

Comment: @Destructor, from the disassembly code by `objdump -dS exe_file`, `080480d8 <_start>:
.globl _start
_start:call main
 80480d8: e8 00 00 00 00        call   80480dd <main>

080480dd <main>:
int main()
{
 80480dd: 55                    push   %ebp
.....
 80480ef: c9                    leave  
 80480f0: c3                    ret ` . After the `call`, the next op is 80480dd. If you don't want `exit()`, make another idea to skip `80480dd~80480f0`.  `_exit()` does

Comment: To call this function anything other than `_start`, use `-e` linker option to set entry point: `gcc -nostdlib -Wl,-efunction1`

Comment: Note that the stack is aligned differently on entry to `_start`: no return address on the stack so it's still 16-byte aligned.  But GCC will assume that it's a normal function, so it will violate the ABI when it calls other functions.  Use `-mincoming-stack-boundary=2` for that file [(docs)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) to tell GCC that the stack might only be 4-byte aligned on function entry, or maybe an `__attribte__((target("something")))` just on `_start`

Comment: Update: [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283880) shows how to define a `_start` in C if you really want to abuse the compiler this way, using `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))`.

Comment: I had to also specify "-no-pie" to get a proper executable binary, where `file` says "a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64" instead of "a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked"

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to is compile the C code to object files (`gcc -c` to get some `*.o` files) and then link them directly with the linker (`ld`). You will have to link your object files with a few extra object files such as `/usr/lib/crt1.o` in order to get a working executable (between the entry point, as seen by the kernel, and the `main()` function, there is a bit of work to do). To know what to link with, try linking with the glibc, using `gcc -v`: this should show you what normally comes into the executable.

You will find that gcc generates code which may have some dependencies to a few hidden functions. Most of them are in `libgcc.a`. There may also be hidden calls to `memcpy()`, `memmove()`, `memset()` and `memcmp()`, which are in the libc, so you may have to provide your own versions (which is not hard, at least as long as you are not too picky about performance).

Things *might* get clearer at times if you look at the produced assembly (use the `-S` flag).

Comment: I have to use _start instead of main, but when I try to call a libc function gcc doesn't complain. Does the libc-link disappear if I remove all libc-calls?

Comment: Not directly. If you try `gcc -v`, you will see that `gcc` gives some object files to the linker (the `*.o`). The linker includes all object files it is given. "Disappearance" occurs only with libraries (`*.a`) because they are repositories of object files that the linker is free to use or not to use.