# Can system calls be invoked in source code, without a library that doesn't come with the OS?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

System call functions are offered by an OS directly.
Some libraries (e.g. the GNU C library) offer functions that wrap the system calls of the OS, but are not offered by the OS directly.

In Linux, can I invoke system call functions in my C code, without a library (e.g. GNU C Library) that isn't offer by the OS directly? Does the OS offer a library for its system calls?

For example, if I want to directly invoke the system call function `read()` in my C program, which header file should I include? Do I have to use some library?

Comment: unistd.h provides access to the read function.

Comment: fwiw you can call syscalls in asm without needing a library: http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html syscall table: http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

Comment: With assembler `int` instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling without libc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548486/compiling-without-libc)

Comment: The CNU C library is not magic. It is just some perfectly normal code. You can write your own code that does exact same things.

Comment: By the way the GNU C library *is* provided by the OS. They don't insist on calling it GNU/Linux for nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

The headers you want are usually in `/usr/include/linux`.

The lowest-level way to make a syscall is with the `INT 0x80` assembler instruction directly, which is of course available to you without any libraries at all.

Comment: In complement, there is the function `syscall` in <unistd.h> or <sys/syscall.h>, which calls INT 80 with the syscall id you want and the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. (1) what is the name of library in /usr/include/linux?  (2) Does the concept of "library" not exist in assembly language? Do assembly language has a concept similar to "library" or in place of "library"?

Comment: Include directories contain headers, not linkable libraries. The linux directory contains headers with constants for things like syscall numbers. No, assembler doesn't have "libraries" the way you're using the word - the closest thing would be to static link some C code, but you explicitly said you wanted to do this without anything like glibc, which is where the unistd code comes from.