# Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi3, nrf52

I am building `zephyr` on `Raspberry Pi 3b` to use `nRF52840 dongle`. Follow the tutorial [Getting started with Zephyr](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/getting_started/getting_started.html)

Everything includes:

- download
- install
- `cmake -DBOARD=nrf52840_pca10059 ..`

was ok until I `"make"` in build/, issue occurred:

> /home/pi/zephyr/ext/hal/cmsis/Include/core_cm4.h:105:8: error: #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"
>    #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"

Has anyone:

- used `Zephyr` with `RasPi 3b`?
- used `RasPi 3b` with `nRF52840 dongle`?
- can solve this problem?

Comment: You are using GCC or what?

Comment: Since it is an ARM chip you could probably disable it with `-mcpu=name+nofp` where name specifies your ARM chip. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's true, I am using gcc, it's gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf on Pi.

Comment: Hi, I tried `cmake -DBOARD=nrf52840_pca10059 -mcpu=cortex-m4+nofp .. ` but nothing has changed

Comment: Thank you, finally I solved my problem followed your guide. 
I choosed wrong gcc: `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`, the right one is: `arm-none-eabi` and `cmake -DBOARD=nrf52840_pca10059 -mcpu=cortex-a53+nofp+nosimp .. ` 
Thank you again, you made my day :D

Answer (score 3):

The GCC that you were using `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` is the incorrect gcc to use. You should be using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` which the PI uses specifically.

Along with that, you can disable the generation of FPU instructions and SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) by using `-mcpu=name+attribs` where it might be `-mcpu=cortex-a53+nofp+nosimd`.

See [http://gcc.gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) for documentation on -mcpu.

Comment: Disabling the FP with '-mcpu' or any other compiler option won't work for 99% of programmers.  The 'glibc' will be with *hard float* and you can't use `malloc`, `strlen`, etc.  You have to also use `-nostdlib` and maybe `-freestanding`.  See: [Compile without libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548486/compiling-without-libc), [blog hello world without libc](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/hello-from-a-libc-free-world-part-1-v2), etc.  Getting the proper gcc is the answer for  people.  You might do `-freestanding` for a boot loader before the FPU is enabled, etc, but not the OP.

Comment: Ahh I see, unless glibc is compiled with the right options. However, I think it worked for them because glibc already doesn't use hard floats due to the board not having a FPU.

Comment: *glibc* is part of the compiler; it is a library provided with the host `gcc` executables.  The *glibc* will have FPU instructions and expect float arguments in a VFP registers.  Using it may seem to work but will result in unexpected crashes.  For instance `memset` and `memcpy` may decide to use NEON registers as this can be faster.  It is very irresponsible to use the *glibc* that is compiled with hard float.

Comment: There are other 'multi-lib' gcc with both hard and softfloat.  Getting the right compiler is the right thing to do.  You should compile with `-freestanding` if you intend to use the hf tools on a non-FPU system.  This has many issue to resolve depending on the 'C' features you use.