# Where does GCC find printf ? My code worked without any #include

Tags: c

I am a C beginner so I tried to hack around the stuff.

I read `stdio.h` and I found this line:
`extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);`

So I wrote this code and i have no idea why it works.

code:

```
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

output:

```
sh-5.1$ ./a.out 
Hello, World!
sh-5.1$
```

Where did `GCC` find the function `printf`? It also works with other compilers.
I am a beginner in C and I find this very strange.

Comment: *"Where did GCC find the function printf? "* - The standard library, which was implicitly linked unless you said otherwise via build-config. Headers contain the road map; the libs contain the actual city. You just ripped a scrap of paper from the map and threw it in your source file, but the lib is what makes this all come together.

Comment: That being said, you should generally `#include <stdio.h>` instead of copying the prototype yourself if you intend to use any compiler, version, and settings different from the compiler, version, and settings you are using now.

Comment: You would have had to ignore the compiler warning about the implicit definition of `printf()`. E.g. `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] printf ("foo\n");` and `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’` with the `note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’` Never accept code until it compiles without warning. Including `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc will link your program, by default, with the c library `libc` which implements `printf`:

```
$ ldd ./a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd5d7d3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdf2d307000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdf2d4f0000)

$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep ' printf' | head -1
0000000000056cf0 T printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

If you build your program with `-nolibc` you have to satisfy a few symbols on your own (see
[Compiling without libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548486/compiling-without-libc)):

```
$ gcc -nolibc ./1.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x26): undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/user/1000/ccCFGFhf.o: in function `main':
1.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `puts'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between the compile and link phases of program compilation.

In the compilation phase you describe to the compiler the various things you intend to call that may be in this file, in other files or in libraries. This is done using function declarations.

```
 int woodle(char*);
```

for example. This is what header files are full of.

If the function is in the same file then the compiler will work out how to call it while it compiles that file. But for other functions it leaves a note in the generated code that says

```
please wire up the woodle function here so I can call it.
```

Usually called an `import` and there are tools you can use to look at the imports in an object file - name depends on platform and toolset

The linkers job is to find those imports and resolve them. It will look at objects files passed on the command line, at libraries included on the command line and also standard libraries that the c standard says should be available to all programs.

In your `printf` case the linker found `printf` in the c standard library that the linker includes automatically.

BTW - the linker looks for 'exports' from objects and libraries, there are tools to look at those too. The linkers job is to match each 'import' to an 'export'

Answer (score 1):

That your program *compiles* without a header present means that the compiler settings were lenient. You should still get a warning though. The reason that your program *links* is that the C standard library, which contains the code of the function `printf`, is linked automatically. Almost every C program needs it because input and output, or generally interaction with peripherals, which that library handles, are the general means of generating a "side effect", an effect outside the program. The opposite is so uncommon that one must make the wish to *not* link with it explicit.

**So why does your compiler accept a call to a function which has not been declared?**

C emerged at a time when programs were much smaller and software development as an engineering discipline didn't formally exist:

> Four years later [i.e., in 1978], as a still-junior faculty member, I tried to get my colleagues [...] to create an undergraduate computer-science degree. A senior mechanical engineer of forbidding mien snorted *surely not:* Harvard had never offered a degree in automotive science, why would we create one in computer science? I waited until I had tenure before trying again (and succeeding) **in 1982.** -[Harry R. Lewis](https://www.harvardmagazine.com/2020/09/features-a-science-is-born)

That was about 10 years after Denis Ritchie had started to develop this versatile new programming language, the successor to B. The problems involved in creating and maintaining large programs back then were simply not as pressing and not as well-understood as they are, perhaps, today.

Among the many things that help us today, at least in most compiled languages, is *strong typing.* Every identifier we use is declared with a static type. But the importance and benefits of that were not that obvious in the 1970s, and early C permitted mixing and matching integers and pointers at will. It's all numbers, right? And a function is just a name for a jump address, right? The user will know what to put on the stack, and the function will read it off the stack — I really don't see a problem here ;-). This attitude brought us functions like `printf()`.

After this stage-setting we are slowly getting to the point. Because a function is just a jump address, *no function declaration needed to be present in order to to call one.*  The assumed parameters were what you presented, and the presumed return type defaulted to int, which was often correct or at least didn't hurt. And for a long time C kept this backward compatibility. I think the C99 standard forbid the use of undeclared identifiers, and the standard drafts for C11 and C21 both say:

> An identifier is a primary expression, **provided it has been declared** as designating an object (in which case it is an lvalue) or a function (in which case it is a function designator)<sup>91</sup>

Footnote 91 says "Thus, **an undeclared identifier is a violation of the syntax**." (All emphasis by me.)

All compilers [I tried](https://www.godbolt.org/z/dK1rf61zr) compile it anyway (with a warning), perhaps because some ancient code that still gets compiled frequently depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, realize what the `gcc` program *is*. Technically, it is not a compiler, but a compiler driver. A compiler driver is responsible for driving the various other tools which perform compilation-related tasks. Some of the tools are found in `PATH`, whereas others are in internal compiler directories.

There are various ways to check what the driver is doing. I won't go into much detail about how I made the rest of this post, but briefly:

- `strace -f -e %process gcc` is a Linux-specific way of showing all the programs executed (elsewhere in this answer, I assume Linux when specifying details but it doesn't matter)
- `gcc -v` will dump out various information, but you have to learn what parts actually matter for whatever you are doing.
- there exists a "specs" file that controls some of the argument-related stuff the driver does

---

Now for the actual data:

Here's the tree of processes that `gcc` might execute:

- `gcc`, the "driver" (input various, output various. Some arguments are handled by the driver itself, but most are passed to the various subprocesses)

  - (these are repeated for every input file. If `-pipe` is passed, temporary files are omitted and processes are run in parallel; if `--save-temps` is passed, intermediate files are preserved):

    - `cc1 -E -lang-asm`, the "preprocessor" for assembly code (input `.S`, output `.s` - yes, case matters. Only relevant if you're trying to compile separate ASM  files that need preprocessing)
    - `cc1 -E`, the "preprocessor" for C code (input `.c`; output `.i`. Only a separate process if `-fno-integrated-cpp` is passed, which is rare. Note that the `cpp` program in `PATH` is never called, even though it is provided by GCC - rather, it calls this. If `-E` is passed, the driver stops after this)
    - `cc1`, the "compiler" proper (input (usually) `.c` or (rarely) `.i`; output `.s`. If `-S` is passed, the driver stops after this; if `-fsyntax-only` is passed, this stage doesn't even complete)
    - (For other languages, replace `cc1` with `cc1plus`, `cc1d`, `cc1obj`, `f951`, `gnat1`, etc. Note that the different drivers like `g++`, `gdc`, etc. only affect what extra libraries are linked by default)
    - `as`, the "assembler" (input `.s`; output `.o`. This is looked up in `PATH`; it is shipped as part of Binutils, not GCC. If `-c` is passed, the driver stops here)
  - `collect2`, the "linker" wrapper (supposedly this has something to do with constructors, and potentially calls `ld` twice, but in practice I've never seen it. Just think of it as forwarding all its arguments to `ld`, even if you have constructors normally)

    - `ld`, the "linker" proper (input `.o` or others (assumed to be libraries); output executable or shared library. Like `as`, this is actually part of Binutils, not GCC, so it is looked up in `PATH`)

The driver has a *lot* of logic, so it is important that you use it. Notably, you should never call `as` or `ld` yourself, since that will omit arguments that rely on the driver's sense of "exact current platform".

---

Now, getting to your specific question:

Ignoring irrevelant arguments and simplifying paths, the `ld` call ends up looking like:

```
ld -o foo Scrt1.o crti.o crtbeginS.o foo.o -lgcc -lgcc_s -lc -lgcc -lgcc_s crtendS.o crtn.o
```

The various "crt" loose object files are a mixture of parts of GLIBC and GCC, needed to support the C runtime (note that there are others as well; which are linked depends on arguments). The `gcc` and `gcc_s` libraries are needed to run code on the platform at all; they are repeated because they rely on the `c` library which also relies on them.

Since `-lc` is passed by default (regardless of language), the `printf` symbol can be resolved. Notably, `-lm`, `-lrt`, `-lpthread` and others are *not* passed by default, so other symbols from differents parts of the C library will not be resolved unless you pass them manually.

All of this is completely independent of what headers are included.

Comment: "cc1, the "compiler" proper (input (usually) .c or (rarely) .i;" what is a .i file ??

Comment: @luca112358 I mentioned it briefly above: `.i` is the output of the preprocessor.